# Mysql to MS SQL Migration and synchronization

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration, ssma

Database migration from MySQL to MS SQL using SSMA tool is very nifty, however,  I have one question around this.
I have 2 MySQL Db's want to migrate to MS SQL, one sizes around 850 GB and another one around 450 GB, there are few tables have millions of records and migration take a day only for such tables.
I was searching for a solution, if there is any way we can keep synching the data from source to destination after doing the first full pull migration.
Your guidance is much appreciated.
Thank you,
Indra

Comment: Have you look at SSIS?